# how to know the version of lib in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I work in Qt5.9.3, writing a qml program in linux platform without x window.

Following is my code:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.13

Entity {
    id: sceneRoot
    ...
    Transform{
        id: torusTransform
        scale3D: Qt.vector3d(1.5, 1, 0.5)
        rotation: fromAxisAndAngle(Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0), 45)
    ...
}
```

However ,there is a underline in Transform in Qt creater.
The underline in Transform means something error happened.I am sure that  Qt53DCore lib has added in .pro file.
So my question is:

How can I know the version of Qt3D.core ?
And how to ensure the specified qml type in the lib?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are a easy way but you can check the old Qt documentation to have an idea of which version you need.

[In your example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qt3d-core-qmlmodule.html) you should use import Qt3D.Core 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I search the "Entity" keyword in Qt5.9.3 folder, in .../Qt5.9.3/qml/Qt3D/Core path, there is a file named plugins.qmltypes.

I open it and found the code:

```
    Component {
    name: "Qt3DCore::Quick::Quick3DEntity"
    defaultProperty: "data"
    prototype: "Qt3DCore::QEntity"
    exports: ["Qt3D.Core/Entity 2.0"]
    exportMetaObjectRevisions: [0]
    Property { name: "components"; type: "Qt3DCore::QComponent"; isList: true;  isReadonly: true }
    }
```

"exports: ["Qt3D.Core/Entity 2.0"]" tell me the version and qml type name.